# В чём разница между стеком ядра и стеком пользователя?

Tags: c#, windows, многопоточность

Изучаю из чего состоит поток и застрял на стеках.
С пользовательским стеком вроде как всё понятно. Это стек, который создаётся на каждый новый поток, занимает 1 МБАЙТ в памяти, содержит информацию о локальных переменных в памяти и адрес о том откуда начнёт исполнение поток после того, как текущий поток вернёт управление. Данный стек не может сжиматься, он может только расширяться.

А вот со стеком ядра уже возникли трудности. Я так понимаю стек ядра так же создаётся на новый поток. Но я не могу понять, что конкретно из себя представляет стек ядра. Когда используется тот или иной стек, это зависит от того в каком режиме запущен процесс?

В общем поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я думаю, что эти знания не принесут пользы, ну только если вы не собрались писать драйверы, работающие на уровне ядра. Короткий ответ - механически разницы нет, логически есть - на уровне прав доступа. Многопоточность кстати не имеет никакого отношения к стеку, ну кроме знаний о том, что у каждого потока свой стек. То есть стек и поток - неделимое целое, да, а вот многопоточность к сути вопроса отношения не имеет, так как речи о множестве стеков не идет.

Comment: @aepot, я указал "потоки", система сама изменила на "многопоточность"

Comment: ну тогда все ок, метка "потоки" является синонимом метки "многопоточность", что в принципе логично

Answer (score 1):

Стек пользователя - это место в памяти, где хранятся данные о выполнении кода программы в пользовательском режиме.

Стек ядра - это место в памяти, где хранится информация о выполнении кода операционной системы и системных функций.

Зачастую стек пользователя используется, когда процесс выполняется в пользовательском режиме, а стек ядра - когда процесс переходит в режим ядра, например, для выполнения системных вызовов или обработки прерываний. Когда процессор переключается между режимами, он также переключает стеки, чтобы сохранить и восстановить соответствующие контексты выполнения.

Comment: Если у меня процесс запущен в пользовательском режиме, то у меня будет создан стек ядра?

Comment: если процесс запущен в пользовательском режиме, будет создан лишь user stack

Comment: @Sheud ни один процесс не может работать в режиме ядра, это запрещено, поэтому да.

Comment: @aepot, я немного запустался)) То есть мы не можем создать процесс, который будет работать в режиме ядра?

Comment: @rotibor не можем, в режиме ядра может работать только драйвер уровня ядра, ну и само ядро. Там кстати совсем другой мир :) В общем, не забивайте себе голову. Почитать ради любознательности конечно про это всё можно, и даже полезно для расширения кругозора, но толку этих знаний не будет до тех пока вы сами что-то под ядро писать не начнете.